# How to get Typed.JS to work properly? Using a variable instead of a pure string;

Tags: javascript, typed.js

This is my first question on StackOverflow, so I hope I'm including all the necessary. If not, please let me know and I will amend accordingly.

I'm trying to get Typed.JS to work on this Roman numeral converter page. I would like the converted number to render with the "typing" effect, but I can't get it to work.
The number does render and I don't see any errors in the console, but the typing effect is missing.

In my script.js file, I have imported Typed and also included it in the HTML (I couldn't understand if only one of them was necessary. The docs don't say much)

`import Typed from typed.js;`

`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/typed.js@2.0.12"></script>`

and the function that includes it is as per below. It takes the user input as argument/parameter and displays it on the page.

This is the repo link: https://github.com/Antonio-Riccelli/js-roman-numeral-converter

```
function outputRomanNumeral(roman) {
    let options = {
    strings: [`${roman}`],
    typeSpeed:90,
    };

    let par = document.getElementById("output");
    par.classList.remove("bg-danger", "text-white", "error-message")
    let typed = new Typed('#spanOutput', options);
    par.classList.add("border-bottom", "border-dark", "border-2");
}
```

Appreciate any feedback you can provide. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the way you are importing `typed.js` is incorrect. You need quotes around it, although that wouldn't actually work either. You are trying to import it when you have the `typed.js` NPM package installed, but that only works if you have a module bundler such as Webpack.

In your case, there are a couple of things that *might* work.

1. Import from CDN. `import Typed from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/typed.js@2.0.12";`
2. Use the script tag, the library might use globals.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I've tried doing as you say and imported it only using the CDN. Something happens, but the page goes crazy: it seems to backspace what was already in the InnerText in a loop, rather than typing the new input. See here: postimg.cc/BjqbKZY0